# Key event in html doesn't throw the function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple problem but I can't find where it comes from.

In an Angular component, I want to use some keyboard events.

Here's my code :

```js
keyDownUp(e){
    //some code to test.
    if (e.keyCode == 16){
      if(this.shiftDown) {
        this.shiftDown=false;
      } else {
        this.shiftDown=true;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div (mouseup)="mouseup()" (mouseleave)="mouseleave()" (mousemove)="mousemove($event)" (keydown)="keyDownUp($event)" (keyup)="keyDownUp($event)" [ngClass]="{'disable-text': dragStatus ===true}">
```

Here the mouse events work but the key ones don't (the function `keyDownUp` isn't activated).

I can't see any faults in the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need focus on your div for key events to occur. 
To make your div focusable you can add `tabindex="0"` to your div. 
It will do the work